# Is she lying on the phone?

Tags: plot-explanation, bridges-of-madison-county

In [Bridges of Madison County](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bridges_of_Madison_County_(film)), Johnson received a phone call and she is having a conservation with someone on the phone.

[image]

Johnson says:

> I hear he's some kind of photographer or something.

She already knows the National Geographic photographer very well, so why does she say **some kind of photographer or something** on the phone.

Is she lying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**YES.  SHE'S LYING.**

Francesca knows that news in the small Iowa town that she lives in travels fast and gossip travels faster.  She is well aware that if she admits to anyone that she knows all about Robert and that she spent the afternoon with him earlier...and that he is in her house at the moment, that the gossip would be unforgiving.

Francesca knows how people, especially women are treated in that town if adultery is whispered about.  The film shows how Lucy Delaney is treated by the people in town over gossip about her committing adultery with a married man.

Francesca's husband is well respected in that town.  She loves her husband and children too much to ruin them in that town with gossip.  That's why she acts as if she doesn't really know or care about Robert.